# I canot add Mobile SDK (Sun Wireless Toolkit) to IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, java-wireless-toolkit

I have IntelliJ IDEA 10.3 Community Edition installed along with JDK 1.6 which has been working fine for Android development.

Now that I am trying to develop J2ME applications, I installed Sun WTK 3.0, but I am unable to add it to IDEA since there is no "Add mobile SDK" option in Project Structure dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java ME plug-in is [not available](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) in the Community Edition. It is supposed to be available from `Settings` | `Plugins`, but for some reason it was not published there.

The solution would be to [download and Ultimate Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) and copy `IDEA_UE/plugins/j2meplugin` into `IDEA_CE/plugins`.

There is an [open issue for this problem](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-68105).