# Java ME in Intellij CE

Tags: intellij-idea, java-me

This question has been asked a couple of years ago, but it didn't get answered.

I added the Java ME plugin from the Ultimate Edition as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590853/i-canot-add-mobile-sdk-sun-wireless-toolkit-to-intellij-idea).
I created a simple Hello World program to test it. I set the ME SDK 3.4 as the project sdk.

I also added the midlet at Project Structure > Modules > Mobile Module Setting > Defined Midlets.

The code compiles okay, but when I try to run it I get the following error:

> Installing suite from: file:///C:/Users/Stan/.IdeaIC13/system/caches/temp2565880090933730950.jad
>   Either the configuration or profile is not supported

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a similar issue with trying to get JAVA ME to work in Netbeans. I am unfamiliar with IntelliJ however the error you have is generally caused by not adding the Main Midlet to your configuration in your IDE.

Right click your project file and see if you can find MIDlet settings, then specify the Main Midlet and you should be good to go!

Fenix

Comment: I already tried that, but it doesn't seem to work. Also, I tried this in netbeans and it works great. Thanks anyway!